# Wrong iteration through df with predict function

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, row

Im trying to iterate through df rows with function but results of that func are the same for all rows.

df like this:

```
text = [ 'Wade, D. T. (1992). Measurement in neurologica' ,'Wade, Derick T. "Measurement in neurological r...']
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':text})
df
```

text

0   Wade, D. T. (1992). Measurement in neurologica

1   Wade, Derick T. "Measurement in neurological r...

```
def predict(input):
    predict_input = loaded_tokenizer.encode(str(test_text),
                                 truncation=True,
                                 padding=True,
                                 return_tensors="tf")

    output = loaded_model(predict_input)[0]

    prediction_value = tf.argmax(output, axis=1).numpy()[0]
    return prediction_value
```

And then I try to iterate through each row:

```
df['pred'] = df.apply(lambda row: predict(df['text']), axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, results are different when I use this function for each row separately [0] and [1]. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
df['pred'] = df.apply(lambda row: predict(row['text']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it still returns wrong results. However, they are different this time. The same class for all of them but before it was 2 now is class 0...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the value in the dataframe as a parameter ? your function doesn't seem to use the values ​​in the dataframe at all. Can you try it like this?
`def predict(value)` then `predict_input = loaded_tokenizer.encode(str(value)....`

Comment: It iterates through rows as before, however result is wrong because it is the same for all rows. This is why seems to be problem: def predict(value):
   predict_input = loaded_tokenizer.encode(str(value),
                                 truncation=True,
                                 padding=True,
                                 return_tensors="tf")'''

    output = loaded_model(predict_input)[0]

    prediction_value = tf.argmax(output, axis=1).numpy()[0]
    return prediction_value